# Detachable element in ensure, Eiffel

Tags: hashtable, detach, eiffel

How can I ensure that an element is in my HASH_TABLE, if it is detachable?

```
Current = HASH_TABLE[ARRAYED_SET[G], G]

add_edge (src: G; dst: G)
do
    if attached Current.at(src) as edges then
        edges.put(dst)
    end
ensure
    in: Current.at (src).has (dst)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you try that:

```
add_edge (src: G; dst: G)
do
    if attached Current.at(src) as edges then
        edges.put(dst)
    end
ensure
    in: attached Current.at (src) as edges implies edges.has (dst)
end
```

Comment: Change the postcondition to use 'implies' instead of 'and then': in: attached at(src) as edges implies edges.has(dst)

Comment: I do think that "attached Current.at (src)" is a valid post-condition and should be check also. If you use "implies" instead of "and then", the fact that "Current.at (src)" is Void will be considered a valid state of 'Current' after the procedure and of course it is not the case. So, that is why the "and then".

Comment: The code is a no-op if src isn't attached... you should then specify in precondition: attached at(src)

Comment: True, sorry. I forget that G is not an attached type.